# Masking for date picker in .NET Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

In a C# Windows application form I have displayed multiple date picker controls and I have defined custom format for them (`dd-MM-yyyy`). The problem is that when user enters day then he has to press left key to go to month and then again left key to move to year.

Is it possible that when user enter two digits in day then it automatically move to moth and same is the case with month that after entering two digits it should move to year by itself. Is there any property for it or do I have to handle it manually ?

Comment: This is not possible, nor is there a reliable way to work around it.  Consider MaskedTextBox instead.

Comment: If i use maskedtextbox then how i can provide calender to pick date from calender as well as an option.

Comment: Nothing a button and MonthCalendar can't do.

Comment: @Tanveer the behavior you want for your `DateTimePicker` is very inconvenient unless the typer can always type exactly the day, month, year, while if he types arrow key to switch between the day, month, year fast, he still feels comfortable.

Comment: Sometimes not a popular answer but the DateEdit edit control from DevExpress has this exact feature, set your mask and then set MaskType.DateTimeAdvancingCaret.  Not out of the box but will solve you requirement.

Comment: @KingKing i tried to explain it to client but he insisted on this feature.

Comment: @ScottWylie we do not use any third party control

Comment: Easy to do in WPF. impossible in dinosaur winforms. Does a WPF example work for you? you could integrate that in your existing winforms application via the `ElementHost`.

Comment: @HighCore , no because this is already a deployed application and i don't want to do any change that might create problems in working due to platform requirements or cannot afford a big change as well.

Comment: @Tanveer what platform requirements? which .Net framework version are you targetting?

Comment: @HighCore,  i mean for the time being i am using normal windows form, I am not aware of WPF, if i used WPF then may be it require anything to install on client computer. due to which it can create issues in production. It will be better if i find solution in normal windows form.

Comment: @Tanveer WPF is part of the .Net Framework starting on 3.0. If you're targetting .Net framework 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 or 4.5 the requirement for the winforms thing is the same than for a WPF application.

Comment: @Tanveer as mentioned above by people who have much more expertise in winforms than me, this is NOT possible in winforms, nor will you find any workarounds. That is because winforms is a really old technology no one cares about any longer. Microsoft did not update winforms since 2007. You SHOULD be using current UI technologies which are part of the .Net Framework exactly the same as winforms, but much better, customizable, scalable and extensible and everything.

Comment: @HighCore you are right, i am just afraid of utilizing it in running application. Please mention any Example and i will try it in some separate application.